# Image URL defining

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Ruby on Rails 3.2

My image_tag url is not returning properly. I have been trying the different variations of Ruby Class: File but cannot get the image to show. My clickable links all work.

When I used `File.basename` I get http://x.x.x.x:3000/assets/gxp2140side.png
When I used `File.path` I get http://x.x.x.x:3000/assets/public/files/marketing/ip_voice/gxp2140/images/gxp2140side.png

File.path returns this error when loading image. Is there a route I can use for the hundreds of image links?

```
No route matches [GET] "/assets/public/files/marketing/ip_voice/gxp2140/images/gxp2140side.png"
```

Controller part which loads _files.html.erb

```
base_dir = "public/files/marketing"
@files = Dir.glob("#{base_dir}/ip_voice/#{@filter}/#{@type.downcase}/*.[a-z]*")
@view = "files"
```

My _files.html.erb

```
<% @images = [] %>
    <% @files.each do |file| %>
        <% if file.upcase.include?('.PNG') %>
        <%  @images << file %>
        <% end %>
    <% @images.each do |image| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= link_to (image_tag File.basename(image)), image[/\/.*/] % </td> 
        </tr>
    <% end %>
            <tr>
          <td>
        <%= extension_image(File.basename(file)) %>
        <%= link_to File.basename(file).upcase, file[/\/.*/] %>
          </td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not fully knowledgeable about this. But mine works when I placed my image files inside the `assets/images` folder.

Say I want to access `assets/images/public/my_pic.jpg`
I would use the url such as like this: `assets/public/my_pic.jpg`

Or file `assets/images/foo.jpg` using url `assets/foo.jpg`

Tested just now in Rails 3.2

Comment: This is acceptable for functionality. I plan on making a specific path by adding path onto the File.path return.